# Arduino UNO And SD Card Custom csPin

Tags: sd-card, sd, custom

I've connected SD card module to `Arduino UNO`. I want to use `PIN 10` for `PWM DC motor control` and because of that, I've connected `CS pin` directly to another pin (A3).

SD card is working properly, but after calling `SD.begin(A3)`, it set `PIN 10` to `HIGH`!
Immediately after `SD.begin(A3)` and set that pin to `LOW`, but meanwhile the motor took a small rotation.

I've digged into `SD.cpp` and `Sd2Card.cpp`, but couldn't find where this problem occured!

Any help appreciated....

**The Solution:**
Simply call `SD.begin(-1)` and it doesn't touch `PIN10`. Hope helps somebody else!

Comment: I do not see a difference for pin 10 between SD.begin(A3) and SD.begin(-1), but how do you set the SS pin for the SD card?

Comment: I've grounded SD csPin and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pin 10 is special. It's the *hardware* chip select pin for SPI.  It is integral to the SPI peripheral in the chip.

That pin *must* be an OUTPUT for SPI to operate as master, or INPUT for it to operate as a slave.

It's a stupid design decision by Atmel if you ask me, but there you go.  So basically trying to use SPI at the same time as PWM on pin 10 is "undefined" and to be avoided.

Use a different pin for PWM or if you need more than there are PWM pins available then consider an external PWM control chip.

---

Just probing around to get more detail on exactly how it all works, this is what I have found:

- `digitalWrite()` explicitly disables PWM on a pin.
- The direction of pin 10 defines the SPI operation as master or slave.
- `analogWrite()` sets `pinMode(OUTPUT)`.
- The SD library calls `pinMode(OUTPUT)` and `digitalWrite(HIGH)` on pin 10.

This means that:

- `SD.begin()` will terminate any existing PWM on pin 10.
- Using PWM on pin 10 will force the pin to output rendering SPI slave mode impossible

You *should* be able to use PWM on pin 10 if, and only if:

- You use `analogWrite()` *after* using `SD.begin()`, and
- You never want to use SPI slave mode.

Comment: I am not saying it's a stupid design decision on your part - I am saying it's a stupid design decision by Atmel by tying the SPI operation to the direction of a specific pin.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: 10 must be OUTPUT for SPI master. not important if LOW or HIGH or PWM. only problem is the SD library assuming other SPI device on pin 10

Comment: second upvote for an obviously wrong answer?

Comment: @Juraj What's wrong about it? The issue isn't HIGH or LOW - that is irrelevant. The issue is pin 10 is integral to SPI.

Comment: INPUT for master??? INPUT for slave.

Comment: @Juraj Simple typo. Pretty obvious I'd have thought. Not a reason for it to be "wong" - only a reason for you to point out the typo.

Comment: but then the rest doesn't make sense

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: PWM is OUTPUT. pin 10 can be used for PWM is Atmega is master

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion. PWM is not OUTPUT. It is PWM. It is not controlled by port registers. It comes from the timer.

Comment: analogWrite has pinMode OUTPUT

Comment: So? That doesn't mean anything.

Comment: the register is set, SPI is master

Comment: SS and OC1B are both *alternate functions* on the same pin. You can have one and only one selected at a time.

Comment: I interpret the datasheet and the comments in the library so that if SPI is master, SS is is gpio. only if it would become INPUT LOW the SPI would switch to slave. did you test it with PWM? I didn't see anywhere a note about pin 10 PWM conflict with SPI master

Comment: digitalWrite explicitly disables PWM on the pin. I will dig out one of my old Arduinos and experiment, see what the actual operation is.

Comment: @Juraj I have tested all the different permutations and found where it is and where it isn't possible to use PWM on pin 10.  I have updated my answer with more detail.

Comment: thank you. I just started connecting the SD card of the Ethernet shield to Nano :-)